# After upgrade Boot2Docker 1.5 to 1.6 error append:Failed to get machine "boot2docker-vm": machine does not exist (Did you run `boot2docker init`?)

Tags: boot2docker

After upgrade to docker 1.6

error in run: Failed to get machine "boot2docker-vm": machine does not exist (Did you run `boot2docker init`?)

boot2docker fail to run and nothing to do to restore.

```
boot2docker.exe ssh
error in run: Failed to get machine "boot2docker-vm": machine does not exist (Did you run `boot2docker init`?)
```

and

```
boot2docker.exe init
error in run: Failed to get latest release: Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases: dial tcp: GetAddrInfoW: No such host is known.
```

Comment: May uninstall and install can work. But i want to solve the issue without doing that.

Comment: The rsa directory does not exist any more...

Comment: My mistake have been to upgrade virtual box out of docker install by accepting the upgrade from virtualbox application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official upgrade process](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#upgrade-the-boot2docker-vm-image) is:

```
boot2docker stop
boot2docker download
boot2docker up
```

I have done it in a simple `cmd.exe` session, and it worked perfectly, even behind proxy.

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\b2d>bd download
Latest release for boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.6.0
Downloading boot2docker ISO image...
Success: downloaded https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.6.0/boot2docker.iso
        to Z:\.boot2docker\boot2docker.iso

Boot2Docker version 1.6.0, build master : a270c71 - Thu Apr 16 19:50:36 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651
```

---

`boot2docker upgrade` might not have the expected result (in that it would reset everything, including removing `boot2docker-vm`).
So don't do that.

If you did that, you have to do again a [`start.sh`](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/blob/master/start.sh) which will init (again) and start and new boot2docker VM instance.

---

Regarding the "`dial tcp: GetAddrInfoW: No such host is known.`", see [issue 686](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/686).

You can at least debug the init step with `boot2docker init -v`.

> I have rebooted my system, then I can create my docker container now

The issue also includes:

> You seem to be using the built in Windows `cmd.exe` shell - which is not supported.
>   You need to use the Boot2Docker shell.

---

[Dieter Menne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229794/dieter-menne) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799491/after-upgrade-boot2docker-1-5-to-1-6-error-appendfailed-to-get-machine-boot2do/29819016#comment47822282_29819016):

> "cmd not supported": In theory you are right, but because of a bug parsing the `-v` line, currently you MUST use cmd or Powershell for 1.6 when you have shared folders.
>   See [issue 12590](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590#issuecomment-95471802)
>
> For others: Do no forget to run "`boot2docker shellinit`" in cmd.

Comment: "cmd not supported": In theory you are right, but because of a bug parsing the -v line, currently you MUST use cmd or Powershell for 1.6 when you have shared folders. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590#issuecomment-95471802

Comment: @DieterMenne I agree: I just tested the upgrade (boot2docker download) in a cmd, and it just worked.

Comment: For others: Do no forget to run "boot2docker shellinit" in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to uninstall re-install docker 1.6 same error append.
I have add -v in the start.sh on all boot2docker commands and i have view that:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
```

On the list of network adaptator, i can see only

> VirtualBox Host-Only Network

No "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" listed.
The issue is described here:
https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/48

after check Virtual Bridged Network driver,
[image]

i have relaunched start.sh and **it's work !**

Comment: But after that **boot2docker.exe download** return always:
`error in run: Failed to get latest release: Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases: dial tcp: GetAddrInfoW: No such host is known.`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? It works in my case (with the right proxy variables set)

Comment: Yes,  but the issue append because network adaptator in Windows is not configure properly.