# Docker for Windows doesn't work

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to setup Docker on **Windows 8.1**. I was following this guide: https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#installation It seems nice and straight forward ... except it's not working for me.

The installation passes allright. Then I run the Boot2Docker Start, it says it's initializing and then closes the command line windows. Some sample outputs:

```
C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): windows/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/version: dial unix /var/run/doc
ker.sock: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.. Are you
 trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

_

```
C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>boot2docker.exe delete

C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>boot2docker.exe download
Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.6.2
Downloading boot2docker ISO image...
Success: downloaded https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download
/v1.6.2/boot2docker.iso
        to C:\Users\Antonin\.boot2docker\boot2docker.iso

C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>boot2docker.exe init

C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>boot2docker.exe start
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

I would provide some more information, but I have no idea where to find any logs.

Is there anyone experienced with Docker running on Windows who has an idea what my problem is?

Comment: Can you try the start.sh I mention in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29819016/6309?

Comment: @VonC Just running start.sh? That gives me: 

initializing...
Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists

starting...
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1

My idea of what could help is having more detailed error message than just "exit status 1" which gives me no clues of what may be wrong.

Comment: try and delete the boot2docker-vm, then try again the start.sh

Comment: I was playing with it a bit already, I tried that. Then I get the output:

initializing...

starting...
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1

BTW one more hint. When I was doing the installation for the first time, I remember the last thing I've seen was the key random image. I think I read somewhere that the installer is suppose to ask you for a passphrase for the key (which you can decide to keep empty) ... but mine didn't. If I try to uninstall the Docker and start over, I don't get to that point anymore.

Comment: Ok. I didn't had any passphrase to enter, and my boot2docker does work fine on W8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel hinted, by running the virtual machine image directly in **VirtualBox**, you get more detailed error message.

My error message was exactly the same as Daniel is showing.

The solution is this:

1. Turn on virtualization in BIOS.
2. Make sure it is not being used by something already - common issue is **Hyper-V**. Search for "**Turn Windows features on or off**", untick Hyper-V, restart your computer. Docker should work for you now.

*Of course I had a reason why I had the Hyper-V on, I guess I'll have to make some compromises in order to have the Docker running.*

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check that your bios is properly configured. I ran into this same exact issue, as was able to resolve it by re-configuring my bios. Check the screenshot image below. I was able to see this error message when trying to start the docker-vm manually through Virtual Box. I think the error message could be a little more clear from the boot2docker cli though. The exist status 1 isn't very clear. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I think this may be helpful, I'll check it out tonight.